# How does ActiveRecord convert a hash to JSONB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, pg

I have a hash that contains only string keys and simple datatypes that are compatible with JSON (numeric values, arrays, string, and objects containing the same).

I'd like to know what ActiveRecord (or any other layers involved) does to translate that ruby hash into the SQL statement that stores it in a JSONB column.

Using `rails 4.2.7.1`, and `pg 0.20.0`

Does ActiveRecord just call `#to_json` on the hash, and the resulting `String` is put in the SQL query, and that's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They called `ActiveSupport::JSON.encode` method, as you can see from [lines](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/json.rb#L17-L19).

But later it was changed in this [commit](https://github.com/maclover7/rails/commit/efaa6e4f79d457c2cdd08cbc56d63bc972a6993c), which caused problems mentioned in the bug [ticket](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27788), and the [notes](https://github.com/maclover7/rails/commit/835246e622dc0431af3cb951db22ef78876006af).